# what is the reason for Multiplicity constraint violated.

Tags: .net, entity-framework, orm, entity-framework-mapping

I am having a class A which is having list of another class b

```
Class A
{
  public List<B> PointCollection
   {
   get;
   set;
   }
}
```

Although all other articles tell that Class B might also be containing the object of Class A but it is not the case. when i fill the data and try to save then The role 'A_PointCollection_Source' of the relationship 'A_PointCollection' has multiplicity 1 or 0..1. exception is thrown.
.Note i am not defining relationship rather i am letting Entity framework to define on its own.
So, please suggest the possible solutions

Comment: I haven't investigated but I would expect that the `A` side of your A->B relationship is indeed multiplicity 1 (because a `B` only has a single `A`).  I suspect that you need to post more code - how are you saving this data?

Comment: Actually if i use only above these classes then there is no issue.
but scenarios is as following
Class A
{
  public List<B> PointCollection
   {
   get;
   set;
   }
}
Class C
{
  public List<B> OtherCollection
   {
   get;
   set;
   }
}
Class D : A
{
}
and actually the point collection of class a is filled in Class D and then saved, so i am unable to understand which class is creating problem.

Comment: Can you please edit your question to include code that demonstrates the issue - including both the classes *and* the code you're using the save them.  If the code you posted doesn't replicate the problem then you're making it fairly difficult to help...

Comment: Dan, the line of code for saving process tends to be very large so, i am unable to post the code , moreover if you can tell me the possible reasons for the exceptions, then i can try out those options.

Comment: The possible reasons are that your code is wrong.  There are lots of ways in which it could be wrong!  Most likely, I would guess that the code you're saving to the database with is wrong, but I can't tell *how* without seeing the code.  It could be that your schema is wrong on the database, or that you're using a database server that's not supported by EF, or that you have spelled your column names wrong, or a million other things.  By far the easier way to approach this is to narrow down the problem by actually showing what the code is....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, the issue was due to saving approach we were using, we had a very large code for saving purpose, so some methods were tempering with the PointCollection property and violating the relationship of PointCollection navigation property, so when i debugged the code, I found the error the I approached some other way for updating the PointCollection navigation property.